# Getting this error in Android Studio - Unresolved Reference: nameInput

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

unresolved reference

```
    val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()   // getting error in this line 

    val intent = Intent (this, BirthdayGreetingsActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Can you post the viewgroup if it is editText or textView.

Comment: it's editText 

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

in your XML, you will have a view like

```
   <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/nameInput" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
      android:ems="10" 
      android:inputType="textPersonName" 
      android:minHeight="48dp"
      android:textAlignment="center" 
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

in your activity class
add this

```
 val name : EditText = findViewById(R.id.nameInput)
```

and get the input text with

```
name.text.toString()
```

Comment: Really sorry I tried voting that, as I don't have minimum 15 reputation, I'm unable to.
But I have accepted it

Comment: you do that by tapping on the triangle button, like you want to increment something .. welcome to the community